# MudBlazor custom color theme

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I'm trying to create my custom color theme for a Blazor WASM page where I use MudBlazor. In the `MainLayout.razor` file I added

```
<MudThemeProvider @bind-IsDarkMode="@_darkModeOn" Theme="@_themeDefinition" />
```

and then in the C# code section I initialize the theme field:

```
MudTheme _themeDefinition = new GreenYellowTheme();
```

The GreenYellowTheme.cs file contains the theme (with light and dark mode):

```
using MudBlazor;

namespace MudBlazorTest.ColorPalettes
{
    public class GreenYellowTheme : MudTheme
    {
        public PaletteLight PaletteLight { get; } = new PaletteLight
        {
            Black = "#000000",
            White = "#FFFFFF",
            Primary = "#FF0000",
            Secondary = "#00FF00",
            Tertiary = "#0000FF",
            Success = "#00FFFF",
            Info = "#FFFF00",
            Warning = "#FF00FF",
            Error = "#C0C0C0",
            Dark = "#333333",
            Background = "#FFFFFF",
        };

        public PaletteDark PaletteDark { get; } = new PaletteDark
        {
            Black = "#000000",
            White = "#FFFFFF",
            Primary = "#FFFFFF", //white
            Secondary = "#c5b858", // yellow
            Tertiary = "#1b5e20", // green
            Success = "#00FFFF",
            Info = "#FFFF00",
            Warning = "#FF00FF",
            Error = "#C0C0C0",
            Dark = "#303030",
            Background = "#303030",
        };
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I start the application I see the stock palette from MudBlazor instead of my custom one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems I can see, first the property is called `Palette` instead of `PaletteLight` and the other problem is that the property `PaletteDark` is redeclared and replaces the original property.

Instead you could use the constructor to assign the palettes to the already inherited existing properties:

```
public class GreenYellowTheme : MudTheme
{
    public GreenYellowTheme()
    {
        Palette = new PaletteLight
        {
            Black = "#000000",
            White = "#FFFFFF",
            Primary = "#FF0000",
            Secondary = "#00FF00",
            Tertiary = "#0000FF",
            Success = "#00FFFF",
            Info = "#FFFF00",
            Warning = "#FF00FF",
            Error = "#C0C0C0",
            Dark = "#333333",
            Background = "#FFFFFF",
        };

        PaletteDark = new PaletteDark
        {
            Black = "#000000",
            White = "#FFFFFF",
            Primary = "#FFFFFF", //white
            Secondary = "#c5b858", // yellow
            Tertiary = "#1b5e20", // green
            Success = "#00FFFF",
            Info = "#FFFF00",
            Warning = "#FF00FF",
            Error = "#C0C0C0",
            Dark = "#303030",
            Background = "#303030",
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to use the `Palette` property, VS says it's obsolete and will be replaced in future with PaletteLight and PaletteDark.

Comment: acutally, when I provide the palettes in the constructor, it seems to work. I'm suprised. why does it not work when I initialize the properties?

Comment: OK, I see I was basically trying to hide the properties instead of "overriding" them. But now I'm trying to just assign a new value to `Palette` and VS tells me it's not valid for some reason (I do `Palette = new PaletteLight();`).

Comment: @Val - Didn't know about the obsolete, got it from the documentation: https://www.mudblazor.com/customization/overview#custom-themes . What is the error message you get? The example above worked for me.

Comment: I assume you wrote `_themeDefinition.Palette = new PaletteLight();` , this should actually work-

Comment: Right now my code is what you wrote, ie. I'm creating a new `Palette` object in the `GreenYellowTheme()` constructor and this works. But I was still wondering why I have to use the constructor but can't assign a new instance to the `Palette` *property* in my `GreenYellowTheme` class like this: `Palette = new PaletteLight();`

Comment: Just double checked with the most current version 6.4.1 and there both, the `Palette` (not deprecated) and the `PaletteDark` property, are read/write properties of type `Palette`. This is different to your code, firstly you have a type `PaletteDark` (the type not the property name) and you declared both with a `get` but with no public `set`, this would explain why you cannot set it outside of the constructor.

Comment: I'm not using that code anymore! I'm testing `Palette = new PaletteLight();` now (in the theme class) and this won't work either. The compiler treats Palette as a class name for some reason instead of the property name.

Comment: The example, exactly as you wrote it, is not valid, `Palette` is not a variable, it is a property of the class `GreenYellowTheme`. That's why I asked about `_themeDefinition.Palette = new PaletteLight();` which correctly sets the property 'Palette' of the theme variable instead of `Palette = new PaletteLight();` which tries to assign a new palette to the class 'Palette'.